# Attach messagingServiceSid to a twiml response in nodejs library

Tags: node.js, twilio

I have a webhook setup, and I am able to receive messages and reply to them. I would like to have the responses sent by my webhook to have messagingServiceSid attached to them.

I didn't find on documentation a way to configure that for responses from my webhook, only for new SMS using

```
client.sendMessage({
  messagingServiceSid: 'MG9752274e9e519418a7406176694466fa',
  to: '+16518675309',
  body: 'Phantom Menace was clearly the best of the prequel trilogy.'
}, function(err, message) {
  console.log(message);
});
```

Is there something similar for this code? Is it doable through the UI?

```
app.post('/foo/bar/sms', twilio.webhook({
  host:'gassy-ocelot-129.herokuapp.com',
  protocol:'https'
}), function(request, response) {
  var twiml = new twilio.TwimlResponse();
  twiml.message('This HTTP request came from Twilio!');
  response.send(twiml);
});
```

Images:
[No messagingService on reply messages sent using twiml response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNH15.png)

[Message Detail view from logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NjPL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

As far as I'm aware, there's no way to reply to message from a message service with TwiML.

However, rather than using TwiML, you could just [send the SMS back to your user from the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages) and return an empty `<Response>` to the incoming webhook. Something a bit like this:

```
app.post('/foo/bar/sms', twilio.webhook({
  host:'gassy-ocelot-129.herokuapp.com',
  protocol:'https'
}), function(request, response) {
  // send the message from the message service
  client.sendMessage({
    messagingServiceSid: 'MG9752274e9e519418a7406176694466fa',
    to: request.body.From,
    body: 'Your message'
  }, function(err, message) {
    console.log(message);
  });
  // send empty TwiML response
  var twiml = new twilio.TwimlResponse();
  response.send(twiml);
})
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you receive an incoming SMS on a phone number currently set up to that Messaging Service (via the web ui or phone number REST), then the incoming requests will have `MessagingServiceSid` in the query string.

Comment: Just edited the question for clarity, and added an image. I want to have the responses I send to be linked to the messaging Service.